# Extraer parte de una cadena MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Tengo una tabla llamada `sigo_ticket` de la que extraigo algunos valores para obtener estadísticas, entonces utilizo la sentencia:

```
SELECT comentario FROM sigo_ticket where comentario like "%&&&1%"
```

Lo cual me da como resultado esta tabla:

[image: resultado de query]

Mi duda es, yo no ocupo el texto de `El servicio se da por finalizado`, si no que ocupo la nomenclatura **&&&118;t40;s1470** la cual me sirve para obtener las estadística. ¿Abra alguna consulta que me permita obtener solo la nomenclatura descartando el texto?

Muchas gracias, y saludos!

Comment: Si, el sistema es un sistema de registro y seguimiento de incidentes por lo cual el usuario al cerrar el ticket utilizan el texto de El servicio se da por finalizado &&&118;t40;s1470(ponen cuanto tiempo tomo  y el numero de servicio). mi problema es que el texto el cual cierran el ticket se almacena en un registro y este al realizar el query me trae todo el texto, lo que se tiene que hacer para sacar el tiempo del ticket es utilizar excel y lo hacen todo manual.

Answer (score 2):

Usa el método `substring` donde le pasarás a dicha función los siguientes argumentos:

- Columna a la cual le harás la consulta
- Número de posición desde la cual la función va a seleccionar los valores, asumiendo que el mensaje siempre es el mismo y lo único que cambia es la nomenclatura entonces debes indicar que empiece desde la posición **35** quedando así:

Código

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(comentario, 35) AS Lista FROM sigo_ticket;
```

Lo anterior por que si revisas la *string* te darás cuenta que el primer símbolo de **ampersand** esta en la posición 35, justo después del último espacio en balnco que también cuenta para esta localización.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, a veces los mismos empleados no utilizan el mismo texto, pueden poner EJEMPLO( En total se dieron de alta 80 tickets en el Sistema de AtenciÃ³n a Usuarios, del 02 al 03 de mayo.\r\nEl reporte se da por finalizado\r\n&&&116;t170;s985) a mi lo que me interesa solamente es( &&&116;t170;s985) en el registro pueden a ver diferente texto.

Comment: @JavierLozano es decir la leyenda **El servicio se da por finalizado.** puede cambiar?

Comment: Si, lo unico que esta fijo son los ampersand &&&

Answer (score 1):

Para resolverlo podrías emplear la función `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(comentario,'&&&',-1) as est FROM sigo_ticket where comentario like "%&&&1%"
```

Esto retornaría los datos que continuan a `&&&` por ejemplo:

```
est
--------------------
118;t40;s1470
118;t40;s1550
116;t170;s985
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en el siguiente enlace:

<kbd>[Demostración](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4468f9/7)</kbd>

Espero que sea lo que buscas, saludos.